# Operator precedence of |, ~ and & operator?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence, associativity

I'm confused about these logical operators. can someone please explain the precedence and associative rules of these operators. in bit wise operations, a=011, b=010 and c=001
in d whether a should be negated first or should the evaluation be started from right to left and whose precedence is higher? 
the output is 4, 3,3.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int a=3,b=2,c=1,d,e,f;
 d=~a|b&c;
 printf("d=%d\n",d);
 e=a|b&~c;
 printf("d=%d\n",e);
 f=a|b&c;
 printf("d=%d\n",f);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Funny that one of the top answers from Google will give you http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: A minimum of research is expected of enthusiastic and professional programmers...

Answer (score 2):

C unary operators (e.g., `~`) have higher precedence than binary operators.

`&` operator has higher precedence than `|` operator.

See [man 7 operators](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/operator.7.html) for a summary of operator precedence.